# FM parameter is always <Initial> in SE37

Tags: abap, function-module

We have a function module which contains an importing parameter IS_USER, which is of type S_USER, S_USER is a structure and contains the following fields:

```
USER_ID         USER_ID         CHAR       60
IP_ADDR         IP_ADDR         CHAR       16
SESSION_ID      SESSION_ID      CHAR       20
LANGU           SPRAS           LANG        1
MACHINE_NAME    MACHINE_NAME    CHAR      128
SAP_PASSPORT    SAP_PASSPORT    STRING  
EXTRA_DATA                      STRING
```

When test run the function module in SE37, the parameter IS_USER always have the "<"Intial">" text and no field in it can be modified. Does anyone know what's wrong here?

Answer (score 3):

You need to take the string out of your custom data structure if you want to use SE37 to test your FM.  The SE37 test screen doesn't like deep structures.

If you must use a string you'll need to write a test program rather than using SE37.